How to find an optimal capacitor?
Ok, i suspect it's counterproductive to manually fill excel tables, but not sure how to optimize a capacitor bank.
I need to use all empty PCB space for capacitance. For that i need to select a part number. It starts from the question, whether we maximum height will be optimal, but let's assume that's not a problem.
The question is - how to optimize for price. I assume that capacitance will be more or less maxed out simply because area and height are given - so unless something very exotic is chosen, energy stored will not be different between various solutions. But how do i chose the right price? Is there a correlating parameter? Something close to $/volume.

Sometimes you just have to use your judgement. Just because one combination has the best price today doesn't mean it will a year from now when you are going into production (and buying 10,000x the quantities).

It also depends on your production capability and your electrical performance parameters. Do you want to stack SMD capacitors? Are you really OK using e.g. 10000 0.1uF caps in parallel?

Hard to believe it will be 10000, there is no much space

Energy stored will actually be very different between different solutions. Supercapacitors can store a lot more energy than film capacitors, for instance.
